# Load all data to DropDownList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code below working fine.

**Sample output**

> Computer Department
>
> Technical Department
>
> Product Department

Let say my department is `Product Department`. I am the the who log-in in the `system / project`. It is possible to first load my department in the DropDownList?. What I mean in first load is upon loading of the dropdown my department is set to be the first.

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentDesc", null).OrderBy(m => m.Text);
```

**HTML**

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId ", ViewData["DepartmentId "] as SelectList, "", new { @style = "width:130px;" })
```

Comment: Just set the value of  property`DepartmentId` in the GET method before you pass the model in the view, and that option will be selected

Comment: @StephenMuecke How do I set the property value?.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719293/mvc5-how-to-set-selectedvalue-in-dropdownlistfor-html-helper/41731685#41731685)

Comment: Note also that you cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the SelectList (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode/37162557#37162557)) - rename the `ViewData` property to say `DepartmentList`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Just want to ask. How did you get the `Model.TipoviDepozita`?. Refer to your first link. and what is `"NotAModelProperty", `?

Comment: Not sure what you mean (thats is OP's data) - but you need `ViewBag.DepartmentList = new SelectList(db.Departments.Orderby(x => x.DepartmentDesc), "DepartmentId", "DepartmentDesc");` - or better use a view model

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you provide an example of view model?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133617/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kira).

Answer (score 0):

Where you set null in new SelectList, set your selected option.

```
ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments.OrderBy(m => m.Text), "DepartmentId", "DepartmentDesc", selectedDepartmentId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentDesc",SelectedDepartmentId).OrderBy(m => m.Text);
```

And

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId ", ViewData["DepartmentId "] as SelectList, "My Department", new { @style = "width:130px;" })
```