# selectedValue from view to controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Filter records in index view using dropdown list . How replace xxxxxxx with selectedValue from dropdownlist  to filter. I am not sure how to select the selectedValue from dropdown list in the view. The controller code and the view code is below. I know its a small problem. But I am trying to find for some hours.The filter is working fine if i replace with xxxxxx with 1 , 2 etc.But I want to change xxxxx with selectedValue from Dropdown list.

controller code

```
ViewBag.doctorsid = new SelectList(db.doctors, "doctorsid", "doctorsname",selectedValue);
return View(appointments.Where(d => d.doctorsid == xxxxxxx).ToList());
```

view code

```
@Html.DropDownList("Doctorsid","Select Doctor")
```

Comment: Show the signature of your method (its needs a property `int Doctorsid` to bind to). But this is a terrible approach. Bind your dropdownlist to a model property (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719293/mvc5-how-to-set-selectedvalue-in-dropdownlistfor-html-helper/41731685#41731685) for an example

Answer (score 0):

Use script given bellow

`Script`

```
 $("#Doctorsid").change(function () {
   var doctorsid = $('#Doctorsid').val();
   var url = "/ControllerNmae/ActionResultName/+doctorsid ;
   window.location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: As you suggested I made small changes and included javascript as follows. But the value is not pkckedup.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Model with variables for list and drop down value instead of passing list directly to view 
Controller:

```
ViewBag.ClientTypeID = new SelectList(db.ClientType.Where(ct => ct.IsDeleted != true), "ID", "ClientTypeName");
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClientTypeID, new SelectList(ViewBag.ClientTypeList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class="drop"})
```