# Selected is not set to true when I select an item in DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476530/html-dropdownlistfor-selected-value-not-being-set), but still unclear about the following:

I have a `SelectListItem` that I populate like this:

```
MySelectList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "Text0", Value = "0" });
MySelectList.Insert(1, new SelectListItem { Text = "Text1", Value = "1" });
```

And in my view I display it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyId, Model.MySelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If I select *Text0* and post the model to controller, MyId contains the the selected value, which is perfect.

But when I go through `MySelectList`, the `Selected` value is not set to `true` for any of the items in the list:

[image]

I know I can use MyId to find the selected value, but is there any way to get `Selected` set to `true` when user selects an item from the Drop Down and post the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get DropDownList SelectedValue in Controller in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901175/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-in-controller-in-mvc)

Comment: @Justcode: thanks for this. Are you referring to the answer by Ehsan Sajjad? I might be missing something here, but that answer is explaining how to post the selected text, not setting selected flag.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719293/mvc5-how-to-set-selectedvalue-in-dropdownlistfor-html-helper/41731685#41731685) explains how it works internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not meant to be ever updated automatically by the Framework. When you examine the HTTP Request, you will notice that only the Value for `MyId` is transferred at all. The target View Model, when reconstructed by the Model binder, will not populate `MySelectList` at all, when you see some data in it, that's probably because you're filling it again after the request.

You could, of course, easily perform the Update yourself:

```
var selectedItem = Model.MySelectList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Model.MyId);
if (selectedItem != null)
{
    selectedItem.Selected = true;
}
```

The question is, whether it helps for your further processing.

Comment: thanks a lot. I put a break point in my model constructor and you are perfectly right, the select list item is not being passed in.